# How do I accomplish the following in LDAP?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, jndi, adam, sunone

I would like to accomplish this goal using AD/ADAM

- The ability to make an email or other attributeClass as part of inetOrgPerson globally unique across entries
- The ability to attach a regular expression to an attribute for validation purposes
- The ability to provide a constraint of enumerated choices such as choosing from a list of valid state codes in a state attributeClass

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server or Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do any of that in AD or ADAM.  They're just the data storage repository: I'm afraid you'll have to build the validation code yourself.